# how to install SVN tortoise repository in MAC Machine?

Tags: macos, tortoisesvn

How to install and use "SVN" tortoise Repository into mac machine. I am new in it and I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry tortoisesvn is not available for the mac at the moment. I checked their forums and I don't see a request for it, so you may want to place it? 
http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do

Some people have got it somewhat working with wine/crossover
http://verysimple.com/2009/01/06/tortoisesvn-for-apple-osx/

(link is dead) https://superuser.com/questions/58225/tortoisesvn-for-mac (link is dead)

Alternatives
Some people use SVNX
https://code.google.com/p/svnx/downloads/list
Some people use scplugin
http://scplugin.tigris.org/
versions
http://versionsapp.com/

I have not tried these however. Any form of subversion for mac should work just as well.

If you just need source control there is also git for mac
http://git-scm.com/download/mac